# copy div content to text area onload

Tags: javascript, html

i am using a geolocation script that returns lat and long content into two divs from a postcode search when the submit button is pressed. I need these figures to copy to text areas when the page has refreshed ready to be submitted on a form. I am trying a script that copies from a div to input tag with the onkeyup event but wont work with the onload event. I would be very grateful for any suggestions and please excuse me i am new at this. Thanks in advance.
My code

HTML

```
<Div id="div1">
<input type="text"/id="field1" onkeyup="duplicate()" />
</Div>
<input type="text" id="field2" />
```

JS

```
function duplicate()
{
   var f1 = document.getElementById('field1');
   var f2 = document.getElementById('field2');

   f2.value = f1.value;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that uses onload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6ay5y/1/

Attach a keyup event listener to the first textbox, with a handler that copies its value into the second.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" id="field1" />
</div>
<input type="text" id="field2" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('field1').addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    document.getElementById('field2').value = this.value;
});
```